# What's holding up Russia's OECD membership?

Tags: russian-federation, oecd

There was some [news in 2013](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-g20-russia-oecd/putin-pushes-russias-oecd-membership-idUSBRE91D0VZ20130214) that Russia was impatient to join the OECD.

I'm guessing the intervention in Ukraine and/or Crimea has thrown some cold water onto that, but (insofar) I haven't found any official explanation for the current status of the negotiations.

What are the main sticking points in these negotiations?

Comment: Oh yeah, there's [news from 2014](https://www.dw.com/en/oecd-suspends-russia-accession-talks-while-moscow-vows-symmetrical-sanctions/a-17494773) that the negotiations were suspended. I've only read the title of that insofar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it seems that intervention in Ukraine is one of the major reasons that is a road-block to Russia's OECD membership ([OECD statement, 2014](https://www.oecd.org/newsroom/statement-by-the-oecd-regarding-the-status-of-the-accession-process-with-russia-and-co-operation-with-ukraine.htm)):

> 13/03/2014 - Further to a meeting of its governing Council on 12 March
>   2014, **the OECD has postponed activities related to the accession
>   process of the Russian Federation to the OECD for the time being.**
>
> At the request of the Members of the Organisation, the Secretary
>   General has informed the Russian Federation accordingly.

[Deutsche Welle](https://www.dw.com/en/oecd-suspends-russia-accession-talks-while-moscow-vows-symmetrical-sanctions/a-17494773) provides even more insight for this matter:

> The suspension of accession talks with Moscow came amid **mounting
>   international pressure on Russia over its role in the Ukraine crisis**,
>   which is set to escalate at the weekend when pro-Russian forces in
>   Crimea hold a referendum aimed at seceding from Ukraine.
>
> OECD membership is largely symbolic, but involves a series of
>   examinations on OECD standards in areas such as **democratic freedoms**,
>   tax and environment laws, as well as accounting and statistics rules.